# Image isn't visible in Tkinter output

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

As per the code given below, I want to know what is the problem in it so that I am not getting the wanted output

```
from tkinter import *

# Label = an area widget that holds text and/or an image within a window
# ⬆ - up arrow

window = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file='cap.png')  # creating a usable photo for python as directed in gui 1


label1 = Label(window,
               text="Hello world",
               font=('Arial', 40, 'bold'),
               fg='#4e615e',
               bg='#f4f5e9',
               relief=RAISED,
               bd=10,
               padx=20,
               pady=20,
               image=photo,
               compound='bottom')
# ⬆ label1 is a unique name for our new label and Label() is a function and in the parentheses window is the location of the label and text= is a keyword argument value in the label
# ⬆ the values in red are keyword arguments


# label1.place(x=100, y=100)
# ⬆ This will still pack your label but will give you the power to place it on your wished side

label1.pack()
# ⬆ this will pack up your label and present it in the window, without .pack your label wont be visible

window.mainloop()
```

> **OUTPUT**

[image]

As you can see above ⬆️
The output I want is that my image is compounded in the bottom and the display text is on it's top but the only thing I see is the border and BackGround colour..

---

If I remove the image everything turns out to be fine without it, the text is visible on it's proper position..

---

The size of the image is 100 x 100
Software - PyCharm
MacOS - Monterey

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue in Windows 7, so it may be issue related to the OS.

Comment: Are you certain _this exact code_ will reproduce your problem? Or is it the case that you actually have a function with this code?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, since you are calling `label1.pack()`, there's no reason to also call `label1.place(x=100, y=100)`. Calling `pack` will undo any effects of calling `place`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this is because the image is basically the size of the label...when you remove the image, the label text is shown obviously.
You have to pad the location for the image on the label.

Comment: How to pad the location for the image on the label?

Comment: OP has used `compound='bottom'`, so the text should be shown at the top and the image be at the bottom of the button.

Comment: @acw1668 yes, but what do you mean by button?

Comment: Sorry, typo.  It is label.

Answer (score 0):

I removed: relief=RAISED, bd=10 and it shows the text and the image